# pandoc for Jupyter-to-LaTex | How to render tables?

Tags: html-table, latex, jupyter, pandoc

My attempts to convert from beautiful Jupyter notebook format (with output generated by R code) to publication-ready LaTex format continue.  Tables are not being rendered as desired.

Here’s where I’m at …

- The R data.frame output using Jupyter’s default display DOES convert correctly.
- The R data.frame output using knitr’s kable function and IRdisplay’s
  display_html function renders correctly in Jupyter, but DOES NOT
  render at all in LaTex/PDF – the generated HTML is just ignored in
  the conversion process.
- The R data.frame output using knitr’s kable function and IRdisplay’s
  display_latex function does render correctly in LaTex/PDF, but DOES
  NOT render in Jupyter – only the LaTex code is displayed.
- The markdown table from a markdown cell DOES convert correctly.

Here’s what I did …

little_test.ipynb (a Jupyter notebook) is converted to little_test.tex (a latex document) using pandoc like this:

```
pandoc "little_test.ipynb" --output=”little_test.tex” --to=latex --lua-filter=rah.lua --standalone --extract-media=images --number-sections --shift-heading-level-by=1 --dpi=125 -V documentclass=book -V block-headings -V papersize=letter -V fontsize=10pt -V margin-left=1in -V margin-right=1in -V margin-top=1in -V margin-bottom=1in
```

little_test.tex (a ltext document) is edited slightly like this:

```
\setcounter{chapter}{8}
\setcounter{section}{5} % section number start minus one
…
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=4in]{images/decision-model_pets_provider.jpg}
\end{center}
```

little_test.tex (a latex document) is converted to little_test.pdf (a PDF document) using MikTex’s TeXworks.

Also, notice little_test (from Chrome print).pdf, which is generated by the Chrome browser print applied directly to little_test.ipynb.  Using this alternative approach, all the tables (and all html images) are rendered correctly.  So, I can see there must be some way to do it.  But of course, I’d still need the LaTex so that I can adjust the styling.

How to get HTML-format tables from Jupyter to LaTex? -or-
How to display (kable-generated) LaTex-format tables in Jupyter?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-to-latex-how-to-render-tables/14968?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 1):

The below Lua filter will parse and, if possible, convert all raw HTML blocks in your input. That should make it possible to render tables as HTML, but still have them show up in the final output. Use it by saving the code to a file `parse-html.lua` and pass it to pandoc via `--lua-filter=parse-html.lua`.

```lua
function RawBlock (raw)
  if raw.format:match 'html' then
    return pandoc.read(raw.text, 'html').blocks
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a superb solution!  Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, here's a better overall solution.  Rather than have pandoc convert HTML tables to LaTex tables, I've coded the tables in both HTML and LaTex format within the Jupyter notebook.  The HTML representation will be rendered when running Jupyter; the LaTex representation will be copied as-is by pandoc when converting from Jupyter-format to LaTeX format.

```
x = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(10,20,30), c=c(100,200,300))
x.html = kable(x, format=“html”, escape=FALSE, align=rep(“r”, ncol(x)), caption=“This is from HTML”, row.names=FALSE, table.attr=“style="white-space: nowrap;"”)
x.latex = kable_styling(latex_options=c(“hold_position”),
kable(x, format=“latex”, escape=FALSE, align=rep(“r”, ncol(x)), caption=“This is from LaTex”, row.names=FALSE))
mbx = list(data=list(“text/html”=as.character(x.html), “text/latex”=as.character(x.latex)), metadata=NULL)
publish_mimebundle(mbx$data, mbx$metadata)
```